# Cluster memory usage when calling parLapply multiple times

Tags: r, memory, lapply, rparallel

If calling parLapply multiple times, is it fine to call `makeCluster` and `stopCluster` only once, or should they be called before and after each `parLapply` call?  How does this affect memory usage?

Here's a toy example:

```
library(parallel)

my_g1 <- function(list_element) {
    return(sum(list_element))
}

my_g2 <- function(list_element, my_parameter) {
    return(max(list_element) + my_parameter)
}

my_fn <- function(large_list, max_iterations=10, my_parameter=123) {
    stopifnot(max_iterations >= 1)
    iteration <- 1
    while(TRUE) {
        message("iteration ", iteration)
        list_of_sums <- lapply(my_large_list, my_g1)
        list_of_max_plus_parameter <- lapply(my_large_list, my_g2, my_parameter=my_parameter)
        stopifnot(list_of_max_plus_parameter[[1]] == max(large_list[[1]]) + my_parameter)
        ## Pretend there's work to do with list_of*: check for convergence; if converged, break
        iteration <- iteration + 1
        if(iteration >= max_iterations) break
    }
    return(1)  # Pretend this has something to do with the work done in the loop
}

my_large_list <- list(seq(1, 10),
                      seq(99, 157),
                      seq(27, 54),
                      seq(1001, 1041))  # Pretend this takes up lots of memory, want to avoid copying

unused <- my_fn(my_large_list)
```

Now suppose I rewrite `my_fn` to use a cluster:

```
my_fn_parallelized <- function(large_list, max_iterations=10, my_parameter=123) {
    stopifnot(max_iterations >= 1)
    cluster <- makeCluster(2)  # Two cores
    iteration <- 1
    while(TRUE) {
        message("iteration ", iteration)
        list_of_sums <- parLapply(cluster, my_large_list, my_g1)
        list_of_max_plus_parameter <- parLapply(cluster, my_large_list, my_g2,
                                                my_parameter=my_parameter)
        stopifnot(list_of_max_plus_parameter[[1]] == max(large_list[[1]]) + my_parameter)
        ## Pretend there's work to do with list_of*: check for convergence; if converged, break
        iteration <- iteration + 1
        if(iteration >= max_iterations) break
    }
    stopCluster(cluster)  # With stopCluster here, is my_large_list copied 2*max_iterations times?
    return(1)  # Pretend this has something to do with the work done in the loop
}

unused <- my_fn_parallelized(my_large_list)
```

With `stopCluster` outside the loop, does `my_large_list` get copied multiple times, with the memory not freed until `stopCluster` is called?  In other words, will the memory usage for `my_large_list` be on the order of `2*max_iterations`?  Or will it be constant with respect to `max_iterations`?